# Tree root coming through concrete under shed

Tags: concrete

A tree root has broken through in the corner of my girlfriend's shed slab. It's under a wooden shelving unit from IKEA and one slat if the shelf has been pried loose by the root.

What can I do *about the root*? Do I have to move the whole shed? Redo the concrete surface? Or can I somehow deal with the root in place?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you described the shed a bit (and maybe provide photos). The solution to this with an 8x10 garden shed is very different for the solution for a 30x40 pole shed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva care to revisit this and tell us what you did for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Tough break.... that's gonna be a lot of work. First of all, dig down outside of the shed and cut the root off.... and maybe think about cutting the tree down too. Then, follow the root till you find where it enters the concrete. You'll have to chip away all of the concrete that has been affected by the root (concrete that has been raised up or chipped). If it is just a small portion of the concrete you may not need to shore up the wall that the concrete was holding up. Then, tap con a form to the existing concrete and pour some new concrete in the hole. Might be a good idea to drill a hole through the bottom plate of your wall and put an anchor bolt through the bottom plate and into the area where you will pour your new concrete. This will give you an easy way to anchor your wall back to your new concrete without having to use a hammer drill. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to dig under that slab, find the root and cut it off. Repair the slab with extra thickness. Pray it goes somewhere else next. She is going to appreciate your effort.  Happy Digging.  P.